# Same UUID's for a group of ZFS drives? Are they ok?

Tags: hard-drive, storage, zfs, uuid

Im trying to figure out why my two new drives which are larger than the other 6 are showing equal checksum errors.  In looking into this, I noticed the UUID's are all the same. Is it normal to have the same UUID's like this?

```
$ zpool status
  pool: nas
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices could not be used because the label is missing or
        invalid.  Sufficient replicas exist for the pool to continue
        functioning in a degraded state.
action: Replace the device using 'zpool replace'.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-4J
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 0 days 12:53:46 with 0 errors on Mon Aug  7 06:59:53 2023
config:

        NAME                        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        nas                         DEGRADED     0     0     0
          raidz3-0                  DEGRADED     0     0     0
            scsi-35000cca05884aa50  ONLINE       0     0     0
            scsi-35000cca0588494a0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            scsi-35000cca058852aa0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            scsi-35000cca058852098  ONLINE       0     0     0
            scsi-35000c50093a9182b  ONLINE       0     0     0
            scsi-350000397083ac015  ONLINE       0     0    26
            scsi-35000039708425461  ONLINE       0     0    26
            17872382825322943538    UNAVAIL      0     0     0  was /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c500aeccd07b-part1

errors: No known data errors
```

Is it normaly to have the same UUID for a zfs vdev?

```
/dev/sdf1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="A2885ECD885EA019" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sdf2: UUID="5E2E62DB2E62ABA9" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sdf3: UUID="226e836d-7b8e-424c-b0a0-0397ee458c7c" TYPE="xfs"
/dev/sdf5: UUID="60c94586-7d6a-4e8a-b350-04719990cb69" TYPE="xfs"
/dev/sdf6: UUID="4d91f3bb-8c97-43c8-acea-fb1dd1fe0ed7" TYPE="swap"
/dev/sdf7: UUID="bbc69fc6-12fa-499a-a0c6-e0f65e248ce2" TYPE="xfs"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="nas" UUID="10204323147149787819" UUID_SUB="6584635425097243078" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTLABEL="zfs-132734cdf8c9f4c2" PARTUUID="6c32ae56-c2aa-a744-b387-6c15664472ae"
/dev/sde1: LABEL="nas" UUID="10204323147149787819" UUID_SUB="7415027662888351724" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTLABEL="zfs-376a6cd58d69e2f2" PARTUUID="87b4ec37-cc21-544a-9186-2a14bf6ef88c"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="nas" UUID="10204323147149787819" UUID_SUB="9819349529238006405" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTLABEL="zfs-335c2de359086356" PARTUUID="bc0eba1e-6ec0-ac41-9254-1622f38e168f"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="nas" UUID="10204323147149787819" UUID_SUB="11038151487099663370" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTLABEL="zfs-51d5d511e56fdb77" PARTUUID="d2caa7bf-48ce-2d4d-8b39-6664f1f513a4"
/dev/sdd1: LABEL="nas" UUID="10204323147149787819" UUID_SUB="10380994937332854296" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTLABEL="zfs-122d2866eacc955b" PARTUUID="7ef16354-aab4-3048-91e2-2bd1f9d46723"
/dev/sdg1: LABEL="nas" UUID="10204323147149787819" UUID_SUB="6768350752206510228" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTLABEL="zfs-b0cecfa2ba1e7d10" PARTUUID="c0204fc5-58d1-ca4e-bd8e-73b2ff6700f5"
/dev/sdi1: LABEL="nas" UUID="10204323147149787819" UUID_SUB="9578689271328227841" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTLABEL="zfs-f317a6736bc4baaa" PARTUUID="48cdd444-4af8-6942-8081-ea4ad3bc631b"
/dev/sda9: PARTUUID="13d570a2-d306-194d-84fa-2bb119176f45"
/dev/sde9: PARTUUID="ae55d3b9-ba7c-3d41-956d-21f0f1c0bba1"
/dev/sdb9: PARTUUID="69dff684-38bc-e04d-bce5-9fc17ea9ac80"
/dev/sdc9: PARTUUID="6d6fc257-f983-e540-948d-6fb955439781"
/dev/sdd9: PARTUUID="be43f88a-e235-6641-9dbf-4f1c8d13c6a2"
/dev/sdg9: PARTUUID="a4f58548-c276-c24a-bfcf-776e208f7c8c"
/dev/sdi9: PARTUUID="1fb21d63-5781-eb48-872d-2f7672c682ab"
```

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   2.7T  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0   2.7T  0 part
└─sda9   8:9    0     8M  0 part
sdb      8:16   0   2.7T  0 disk
├─sdb1   8:17   0   2.7T  0 part
└─sdb9   8:25   0     8M  0 part
sdc      8:32   0   2.7T  0 disk
├─sdc1   8:33   0   2.7T  0 part
└─sdc9   8:41   0     8M  0 part
sdd      8:48   0   2.7T  0 disk
├─sdd1   8:49   0   2.7T  0 part
└─sdd9   8:57   0     8M  0 part
sde      8:64   0   2.7T  0 disk
├─sde1   8:65   0   2.7T  0 part
└─sde9   8:73   0     8M  0 part
sdf      8:80   0 465.8G  0 disk
├─sdf1   8:81   0   100M  0 part
├─sdf2   8:82   0   122G  0 part
├─sdf3   8:83   0   500M  0 part /boot
├─sdf4   8:84   0     1K  0 part
├─sdf5   8:85   0 100.3G  0 part /home
├─sdf6   8:86   0   5.9G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sdf7   8:87   0    40G  0 part /
sdg      8:96   0   3.7T  0 disk
├─sdg1   8:97   0   3.7T  0 part
└─sdg9   8:105  0     8M  0 part
sdh      8:112  0   3.7T  0 disk
sdi      8:128  0   3.7T  0 disk
├─sdi1   8:129  0   3.7T  0 part
└─sdi9   8:137  0     8M  0 part
```

Answer (score 1):

That’s the UUID of your ZFS pool. You can see it using `zdb`. Note the `UUID_SUB` values. Those are the member UUIDs, which you can also see using `zdb`.

Example:

```
$ blkid /dev/sdc4
/dev/sdc4: LABEL="arch" UUID="7022611914485952708" UUID_SUB="7409344620062650858" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTLABEL="FreeBSD ZFS" PARTUUID="fc3c9ff3-7457-420c-a8fb-9d4cb73ffd61"
$ zdb
arch:
    version: 5000
    name: 'arch'
    state: 0
    txg: 23397671
    pool_guid: 7022611914485952708
    errata: 0
    hostname: 'server'
    com.delphix:has_per_vdev_zaps
    vdev_children: 1
    vdev_tree:
        type: 'root'
        id: 0
        guid: 7022611914485952708
        create_txg: 4
        children[0]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 0
            guid: 7409344620062650858
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WDS500G2B0A_19196D803086-part4'
            whole_disk: 0
            metaslab_array: 128
            metaslab_shift: 32
            ashift: 12
            asize: 495667642368
            is_log: 0
            DTL: 1674
            create_txg: 4
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 67
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_top: 68
    features_for_read:
        com.delphix:hole_birth
        com.delphix:embedded_data
```

So yes, this is entirely normal and expected.

Comment: Thanks.  I saw the SUB's, but how you explain it makes sense .